# How to adjust a function's returning value with possibility (in AS3 and in C)

Tags: c, actionscript-3, function, random, return

Sorry if I couldn't be clear enough in title. I will give an example. Our function is something like this:

C:

```
int main()
{
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",func(i));
    }
}

int func(int b)
{
if(b>=0 && b<7)
   return 70;
else
   return 30;
}
```

This function (b) will return 70 with 70% possibility and 30 with 30% possibility when 'b' is 'rand() % 10'. But, there must be a more practical way for this. If "that way" exists, I need it both in C (it can be C++ too) and in AS3. Thanks for replies.

---

I just had time to log in and see the replies. Have you ever played any game from paradox interactive? Like europa universalis 3? In that game there are lots of different randomization algorithms. For example, each with 1/3 possibility, you can get something good, nothing or something bad. I want to develop a game which has to have a similar randomization algorithm. I want a function get an input between threshold of 0 and 1, and return one of the consequences which is pre-defined, or a value that I can use to trigger that consequence with a simple switch statement

Something like this:

In AS3:

```
Function randomize(poss:Number):function //here i may need to have more consequences than two. poss value can be an array instead of being a number.
{
Number a = Math.random()
If(a>poss)
Return func1;
Else
Return func2;
}
```

here func1 and func2 are function objects with same input types but differing tasks, and i will use the returned functions like this:

```
Function onClick(evt:Event):void
{
var randFunction:Function=new Function();
randFunction = randomize(0.35);
randFunction();
}
```

But, i don't want to hard code for every occassion that I need 'weighted possibility' like this instance.

P.S: I don't want to have you code for me but having some nice ideas on how to interpret weighted possibility in C and in AS3. If you are not going to contribute, then just don't reply.

Comment: If you're asking us to code for you, than that's not going to happen.

Comment: If you want random behavior then `rand` is the function to use in C.

Comment: Why do you need such weird function both in C and AS3? What do you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Try to read [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) and implement it.

Generate random variate from [0,1] and if below `.7` return `x` otherwise return `y`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think people understood your question (to be fair you were being long winded and unclear) but the answer is quite simple. Store Math.random in a value.

```
var random = Math.random();

if (random > 0.33)
   trace("good")
else if (random > 0.66)
   trace ("nothing")
else trace ("bad")
```

I don't think randomization of any kind can get any more complicated than this.

Comment: His question seems to doesn't contain any question. But, I think what he wanted is this.

Answer (score 0):

The ActionScript 3 version would look something like:

```
function example():int
{
    if(Math.random() >= 0.7) return 70;
    return 30;
}

trace(example()); // Either 30 or 70.
```

Comment: yeah, that works, but I want to have at least two different consequences. Not only two.